# Displaying Portrait and Landscape images in a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been at this for about a week straight, and I'm about to rip my hair out.

I have a UITableView modeled as a messaging app: cells with text, cells with images.  After some VERY extensive testing, I found out that using `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndex` path is a very BAD thing since I'm interested in scrolling my table to the bottom when the view loads and `estimatedHeight` gets confused as to where the end of my table is. So, I'm calculating all heights manually and storing it in a cache that I store and read from disk. (Thoughts?)

That said, I'm trying to display local images.  Portrait images look fine.  Landscape images do not.  Landscape images break auto layout according to the console.

Please take a look at what I have and tell me what the heck I'm doing wrong.

```
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                    NSLog(@"Retrieving local image from documents folder: %@", message);

                    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                    NSString *filePath = /* I'm getting proper file path here */

                    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            MessagesTableViewCell *cell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                            if (cell) {
                                cell.photoView.image = image;
                                cell.photoView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

                                CGFloat aspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height;
                                CGFloat screenRatioHeightMultiplier = 0.6f;
                                CGFloat screenRatioWidthMultiplier = 0.7f;

                                CGFloat maxHeight = (image.size.height / image.size.width) * self.tableView.bounds.size.width;
                                maxHeight = MIN(maxHeight, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height * screenRatioHeightMultiplier);

                                NSLayoutConstraint *aspectRatioConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.photoView
                                                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                                            toItem:cell.photoView
                                                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                                                        multiplier:aspectRatio
                                                                                                          constant:0];

                                [cell.photoView addConstraint:aspectRatioConstraint];

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

As you can see, what I am *attempting* to do is figure out the aspect ratio on the image by calculating the aspect ratio and applying a custom constraint (since I can't do this in storyboard due to the dynamic nature of the images).

I'm using this code in order to figure out dynamic heights of multi-line labels.  Can someone recommend a similar mechanism for images?

```
    static CustomTableViewCell *cell;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: identifier];
    });

cell.textLabel.text = message;
            cell.textLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.tableView.frame.size.width;

CGFloat calculatedCellHeight = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
```

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use contentMode property of UIView according to your requirement

Comment: I wish it worked that way.  The sizes are dynamic, and I can't just create a prototype cell that's an even square.  Even if I did, I still would not know the proper height of the cell given which orientation was in.

Answer (score -1):

As always, crickets in my iOS posts.  I figured out a solution, but not worthy enough to post.

Comment: Then you should delete the question itself. Or post a proper answer.